# Dynamically adjust pipelline presence in scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I currently use

```
custom_settings = { "ITEM_PIPELINES" : { ... } }
```

to set per-spider pipelines. Next, for certain start urls I need to exclude some pipelines. I detect this in `__init__`. Tried to re-assign custom_settings but this didn't work. Is it possible to dynamically change pipeline list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK the custom settings cannot be changed during the run of the spider.

However the solution you are looking here is to add the detection logic to pipelines themselves. For example add extra field to item called `_to_pipeline2` and break your pipeline if it's not present.
For example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    #....
    if item_should_be_pipelined:
        item['_to_pipeline2'] = True
    return item
```

and in your pipeline:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if not item.get("_to_pipeline2", False):
        return item # do not use this pipeline
    # normal pipeline continues otherwise
    del item['_to_pipeline2']
```

or for your case:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if 'http://stackoverflow.com' in spider.start_urls:
        return item  # do not use pipeline 
    # otherwise execute pipeline code here
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work even if I change custom_settings in `__init__`.

Comment: yeah it could be that that setting is loaded in when crawler pulls the spider on crawl initiation so there really is no way modify the pipeline queue after that and would most likely be a really bad idea anyway.

Putting such logic in the pipelines itself is usually preferred approach, even `process_item` receives spider as argument so you can inspect `spider.start_urls` in it and either return/modify an item. I've updated the example to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Before running spider scrapy collects the settings for settings.py. For calling dynamic pipelines or pipeline pass argument from command line:

`scrapy crawl yourspider -a pipeline="Mongo"
or 
scrapy crawl yourspider -a pipelines="Mongo,Elastic,Redis"`

Then use sys for collecting those in settings.py.

`import sys
datastore = None
for arg in sys.argv:
    if "=" in arg:
        splited = arg.split("=")
        if splited[0]=="pipeline":
            datastore = splited[1]`


`ITEM_PIPELINES = {
     'project.pipelines.{}'.format(datastore): 10
}`

That way user can load desired pipeline from command line.